# Subprocces command Python

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to execute my program `./genparams` with python. The source of `./genparams` has this, I think, critical lines.

```
fichier = fopen("params.h", "w");

fprintf(fichier, "#define LOG_LENGTH %d\n", m);
fprintf(fichier, "#define ERROR_WEIGHT %d\n\n", t);

fprintf(fichier, "#define REDUC %d\n", r);
fprintf(fichier, "#define ERROR_SIZE %d\n", len);
fprintf(fichier, "// rounded down from %g\n", res[0]);
fprintf(fichier, "// log_2(binomial(2^%d,%d)) = %g\n", m, t, log_binomial_d(1 << m, t));
fprintf(fichier, "// log_2(binomial(2^%d,%d)) + %d * %d = %g\n", m - r, t, r, t, r * t + log_binomial_d(1 << (m - r), t));
fprintf(fichier, "// security loss is %g\n", log_binomial_d(1 << m, t) - len);
fprintf(fichier, "// final security is %g\n", wf - log_binomial_d(1 << m, t) + len);

fclose(fichier);
fichier = fopen("cwdata.c", "w");
write_precomp(p, fichier);
fclose(fichier);
```

In other words `./genparams` create two files `cwdata.c` and `params.h`, when I run

```
 ./genparams 9 50
```

without python I get these files and the output

```
Security loss is 1.22315
Final security: 20.3993 bits
```

, but using python

```
program = './genparams'
subprocess.call([program, "9","50"])
```

I don't see that files and I get the next output

```
Security loss is 1.22315
Final security: 20.3993 bits
-11
```

What happens here? How I will be able to fix that? Whats means `-11` in the last line

Comment: Add a few more code of where you are doing a `printf` of `Security loss is....` to stdout?

Comment: And perhaps, the -11 is the return code of `subprocess.call` ?

Comment: are you looking in the correct directory for the created files?

Comment: `-11` indicates that your program died from a SIGSEGV signal. Set your core ulimit to infinity (in bash, `ulimit -c unlimited`) and re-run the program. It should dump core. If it does, try `gdb genparams core` to see where it died.